# SGDClassifier with class_weight=auto fails on scikit-learn 0.15 but not 0.14

Tags: scikit-learn

When I train an [scikit-learn v0.15 `SGDClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) with these options: `SGDClassifier(loss='log', class_weight=None, penalty='l2')`, training completes with no error. 
Yet when I train this classifier with `class_weight='auto'` on scikit-learn v0.15, I get this error:

```
  return self.model.fit(X, y)
  File "/home/rose/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.15.0b1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py", line 485, in fit
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/home/rose/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.15.0b1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py", line 389, in _fit
    classes, sample_weight, coef_init, intercept_init)
  File "/home/rose/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.15.0b1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py", line 336, in _partial_fit
    y_ind)
  File "/home/rose/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.15.0b1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sklearn/utils/class_weight.py", line 43, in compute_class_weight
    raise ValueError("classes should have valid labels that are in y")
ValueError: classes should have valid labels that are in y
```

What could cause it?

For reference, here's the documentation on `class_weight`:

> Preset for the class_weight fit parameter. Weights associated with
>   classes. If not given, all classes are supposed to have weight one.
>   The “auto” mode uses the values of y to automatically adjust weights
>   inversely proportional to class frequencies.

Comment: Are you using the same scikit-learn version on OSX? Version 0.15 was just released, maybe you could try it on that. If the bug persists, i.e. the same code raises an error on linux ec2 and not on macosx, then you should consider reporting this to the scikit-learn mailing list.

Comment: I am using Version 0.15.

Comment: Looking at your traceback you are using the beta1, not the release 0.15

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this may be a bug within scikit-learn. As a work around, try the following:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
y_encoded = le.fit_transform(y)
self.model.fit(X, y_encoded)
pred = le.inverse_transform(self.model.predict(X))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a fix in this PR:

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/3515

Please feel free to test and report if it solves the problem for you.