# SVC with class_weight='auto' fails on scikit-learn?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I have the following dataset. Im classifiying it with SVC (it has 5 labels). When I want to perform: `class_weight='auto'` like this:

```
X = tfidf_vect.fit_transform(df['content'].values)
y = df['label'].values


from sklearn import cross_validation

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X,
                                                y)



svm_1 = SVC(kernel='linear', class_weight='auto')
svm_1.fit(X, y)
svm_1_prediction = svm_1.predict(X_test)
```

Then I get this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 62, in <module>
    svm_1.fit(X, y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 140, in fit
    y = self._validate_targets(y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 474, in _validate_targets
    self.class_weight_ = compute_class_weight(self.class_weight, cls, y_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/class_weight.py", line 47, in compute_class_weight
    raise ValueError("classes should have valid labels that are in y")
ValueError: classes should have valid labels that are in y
```

Then For a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808821/sgdclassifier-with-class-weight-auto-fails-on-scikit-learn-0-15-but-not-0-14) I tried the following aproach:

```
svm_1 = SVC(kernel='linear', class_weight='auto')
svm_1.fit(X, y_encoded)
svm_1_prediction = le.inverse_transform(svm_1.predict(X))
```

The problem with this is that I get this exception:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 179, in accuracy_score
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 74, in _check_targets
    check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 174, in check_consistent_length
    "%s" % str(uniques))
ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [ 858 2598]
```

Could anybody help me to understand what is wrong with the above aproaches and how can I use correctly the `class_weight='auto'` parameter of [SVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) in order to autobalance data?.

**Update:**

When I do `print(y)` this is the output:
`0       5
1       4
2       5
3       4
4       4
5       5
6       4
7       4
8       3
9       5
10      4
11      4
12      1
13      4
14      4
15      5
16      4
17      4
18      5
19      5
20      4
21      4
22      5
23      5
24      3
25      3
26      4
27      5
28      4
29      4
       ..
2568    4
2569    4
2570    4
2571    3
2572    4
2573    5
2574    5
2575    5
2576    5
2577    3
2578    4
2579    4
2580    2
2581    4
2582    3
2583    4
2584    5
2585    4
2586    5
2587    4
2588    4
2589    3
2590    5
2591    5
2592    4
2593    4
2594    4
2595    2
2596    2
2597    5`

**Update**

Then I do the following:

```
mask = np.array(test)
print y[np.arange(len(y))[~mask]]
```

This is the output:

```
0       5
1       4
2       5
3       4
4       4
5       5
6       4
7       4
8       3
9       5
10      4
11      4
12      1
13      4
14      4
15      5
16      4
17      4
18      5
19      5
20      4
21      4
22      5
23      5
24      3
25      3
26      4
27      5
28      4
29      4
       ..
2568    4
2569    4
2570    4
2571    3
2572    4
2573    5
2574    5
2575    5
2576    5
2577    3
2578    4
2579    4
2580    2
2581    4
2582    3
2583    4
2584    5
2585    4
2586    5
2587    4
2588    4
2589    3
2590    5
2591    5
2592    4
2593    4
2594    4
2595    2
2596    2
2597    5
Name: label, dtype: float64
```

Comment: can you show a sample of your y-labels array? what's its type? `auto` should work if all data types are well expected.

Comment: thanks @JianxunLi for the feedback. How can I show this sample of my y-labels array?

Comment: just `print(y)` and copy the result to the post.

Comment: Can you try this to see whether all elements in y are int? `test = [type(element) is int for element in y]` and then `print(all(test))`

Comment: @JianxunLi I got: `False`. So this means that my labels are wrong?.

Comment: @ml_guy I modified the lines in class_weight.py to suit my needs and seems to work good.

Comment: Try this. `mask = np.array(test)` and then `y[np.arange(len(y))[~mask]]`    What's the result? the code tries to select those non-int elements.

Comment: @Aditya, could you provide some example?. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is it possible for you to upload your data file? (You can use `df.to_csv('my_data_file.csv')` to dump all data into a csv file.) Your code seems to work all fine on my PC with some artificial data. To find out why it fails on your side, I really need to reproduce the error you see.

Comment: Here is the problem: `df.label.unique()`
`Out[50]: array([  5.,   4.,   3.,   1.,   2.,  nan])` You have NaN in y label.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81599/discussion-between-ml-guy-and-jianxun-li).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
df.label.unique()
Out[50]: array([  5.,   4.,   3.,   1.,   2.,  nan])
```

The sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import SVC

# replace your own data file_path
df = pd.read_csv('data1.csv', header=0)
df[df.label.isnull()]

Out[52]: 
                               id content  label
900   Daewoo_DWD_M1051__Opinio...       5    NaN
1463  Indesit_IWC_5105_B_it__O...       1    NaN


# drop those two 
df = df[df.label.notnull()]

X = df.content.values
y = df.label.values

transformer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = transformer.fit_transform(X)

estimator = SVC(kernel='linear', class_weight='auto', probability=True)
estimator.fit(X, y)

estimator.predict(X)

Out[54]: array([ 4.,  4.,  4., ...,  2.,  2.,  3.])

estimator.predict_proba(X)

Out[55]: 
array([[ 0.0252,  0.0228,  0.0744,  0.3427,  0.535 ],
       [ 0.002 ,  0.0122,  0.0604,  0.4961,  0.4292],
       [ 0.0036,  0.0204,  0.1238,  0.5681,  0.2841],
       ..., 
       [ 0.1494,  0.3341,  0.1586,  0.1316,  0.2263],
       [ 0.0175,  0.1984,  0.0915,  0.3406,  0.3519],
       [ 0.049 ,  0.0264,  0.2087,  0.3267,  0.3891]])
```